# Rest Debugger: Cannot convert access token to JSON

Tags: delphi, authorization, rest, bearer-token

I have this webservice with OAuth2 authentication. I need to create a client for it in Delphi, so I'm using the "Rest Debugger", a tool from Embarcadero that helps configuring rest clients.

Problem is, I get the Bearer token from my webservice by other means, I add it in the headers (picture below), but the application returns "Cannot convert access token to JSON".
[image]

I know the token is valid, as I'm able to use it in other clients or tools (Postman, Swagger), it's just the "Rest Debugger" that gets this error from the server.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, or if there's some known issue with this specific tool. I've found some clues that suggests that by default it does some kind of encoding in the headers, but I would like to know for sure from someone more familiar with that tool.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to disable Param Conversion. Open your Parameter and check the Chebox on the bottom of the Form.

Comment: I don't know if it works, but try the Authentication tab, select the OAUTH2 Method in the left select box, and then fill in the access token field

Comment: @fisi-pjm I'm using the standalone rest debugger. It doesn't have that option, but that's  probably what I need

Comment: @Leonard I've tried using the Authentication tab. By putting the Bearer <token> in the "Acess token" field, the app crashes.

Comment: When I add the Aut info to the header (in code) I use
TRESTRequest.Params.AddItem ('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Token , pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
Remember that the Auth info must not be encoded in any way.

Comment: I used the REST debuger in the beginning too, but could never get the auth part there working.
I ended up coding it by hand myself. And the OAuth2 component (as far as I could tell) do not have support for client_credentials.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a UI issue, but the header does not look right to me - it has "=" where it should be ":". Does REST Debugger show *exactly* what it is going to send? Alternatively use something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see exactly what it *is* sending

Comment: @Rafael Copy the Componentes without Parameters and add the Param manually to your TRestRequest lile Eirik A. Said. Than do an TrestClient.Execute and show TRestResponse.JSONValue. Your Way to go is [poDoNotEncode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "REST Debugger" you must check "Do not encode" option when adding the Authorization header.

[image: Do not encode option]

Comment: As he said, there is no Option in his Debugger. Its a new feature that was not provided from the Beginning.

Comment: That's probably what I need. It must be a newer version of Rest Debugger, I'll find it